# Kubernetes apiserver TLS handshake error with webhook for authentication

Tags: authentication, ssl-certificate, kubernetes, webhooks

Iam trying to perform kubernetes webhook authentication using [pamhook](https://github.com/bjhaid/pam_hook). But I get a TLS handshake error at the webhook when apiserver tries to contact it.

Following are the steps I followed:

apiserver IP: 192.168.20.30
pam webhook server IP: 192.168.20.50

1. Created a server certificate for my pam webhook server using the ca.crt present in /etc/kubernetes/pki/ (in master node)

> ```
> > openssl genrsa -out ubuntuserver.key 2048 openssl req -new -key
> > ubuntuserver.key -out ubuntuserver.csr -config myconf.conf openssl
> > x509 -req -in ubuntuserver.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key
> > -CAcreateserial -out ubuntuserver.crt  -days 10000
> ```

2. Started my pam webhook server using this certificate.

> ```
>  ./pam_hook-master -cert-file /root/newca/ubuntuserver.crt -key-file /root/newca/ubuntuserver.key -signing-key rootroot -bind-port 6000
> ```
>
> `I1109 07:21:41.388836    3882 main.go:327] Starting pam_hook on :6000`

3. Created a kubeconfig file as follows:

> ```
>  $cat webhook-config.yaml
>     apiVersion: v1
>     clusters:
>     - cluster:
>         certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
>         server: https://192.168.20.50:6000/authenticate
>       name: 192.168.20.50
>     users:
>       - name: root
>         user:
>           client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/pki/client.crt
>           client-key: /etc/kubernetes/pki/client.key
>     current-context: 192.168.20.50
>     contexts:
>     - context:
>         cluster: 192.168.20.50
>         user: root
>       name: 192.168.20.50
> ```

4. Configured api server manifest file in

   /etc/kubernetes/manifest/kube-apiserver.yaml

   > ```
   > > ...
   > >     - --authentication-token-webhook-config-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/webhook-config.yaml
   > >     - --runtime-config=authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1=true ...
   > ```
5. apiserver gets restarted.
6. Obtain token by requesting pamhook server. (I did this from my master node)

   > ```
   > $ curl https://192.168.20.50:6000/token --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -u root                                    
   >
   > Enter host password for user 'root':
   > eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIiLCJleHAiOjE1MTAyMjY3ODksImlhdCI6MTUxMDIyNjE4OSwiaXNzIjoiIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJyb290In0.3LmHBy_anjR62WNqKICCx_b8YWFpF4HSKMWLmyORU0M
   > ```
7. Made a request to apiserver using this token, which in turn should communicate with webhook to provide authentication. But Iam getting a 401 Error.

> ```
> $ curl -vvv --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIiLCJleHAiOjE1MTAyMjY3ODksImlhdCI6MTUxMDIyNjE4OSwiaXNzIjoiIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJyb290In0.3LmHBy_anjR62WNqKICCx_b8YWFpF4HSKMWLmyORU0M" https://192.168.20.38:6443/api/
>
> {
>   "kind": "Status",
>   "apiVersion": "v1",
>   "metadata": {
>
>   },
>   "status": "Failure",
>   "message": "Unauthorized",
>   "reason": "Unauthorized",
>   "code": 401
> }
> ```

Message at the webhook server is:

```
> 2017/11/09 07:50:53 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.20.38:49712: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

8. [Document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/webhook/) says that api server sends a http request with the token in its payload. If I try to recreate the same call in curl using the token and ca.crt, it gets authenticated.

   > ```
   > >   $ curl -X POST https://192.168.20.50:6000/authenticate --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -d '{"ApiVersion":"authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1", "Kind": "TokenReview", "Spec":{"Token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIiLCJleHAiOjE1MTAyMjY3ODksImlhdCI6MTUxMDIyNjE4OSwiaXNzIjoiIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJyb290In0.3LmHBy_anjR62WNqKICCx_b8YWFpF4HSKMWLmyORU0M"}}'
   > ```
   >
   > {"apiVersion":"authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"TokenReview","status":{"authenticated":true,"user":{"username":"root","uid":"0","groups":["root"]}}}

But when it is requested by apiserver, TLS handshake gets failed.

My understanding is that the TLS verification is done by checking against the `certificate-authority` file mentioned in `webhook-config.yaml` right? If so, the TLS verification should have been successful with `ca.crt`. But it is failing.

Does that mean api server is performing validation using some other CA? Which CA does it use? How do I go past this TLS verification successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've fixed this. The mistake I've made is I used IP of the webhook server throughout (192.168.20.50 in this case). I replaced it with the FQDN of the webhook server machine and things worked out.

I changed IP to FQDN in the following places:

1. CN while generating the server certificate
2. `-server` field in the `kubeconfig` file

> ```
> $cat webhook-config.yaml 
> apiVersion: v1
> clusters:
> - cluster:
>     certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
>     server: https://ubuntuserver:6000/authenticate
>   name: 192.168.20.50
> users:
>   - name: root
>     user:
>       client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/pki/client.crt
>       client-key: /etc/kubernetes/pki/client.key
> current-context: 192.168.20.50
> contexts:
> - context:
>     cluster: 192.168.20.50
>     user: root
>   name: 192.168.20.50
> ```